# Modify query generated by Linq dynamically

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, iqueryable, dynamic-linq

I'm working on a project that is using Oracle and DynamicLinq, results that DynamicLinq is building a query that is really slow:

```
      SELECT /*FIELDS*/ FROM MYTABLE WHERE (("STRT_DT" >= TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-07-09 
00:00:00.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')) AND 
        ("STRT_DT" <= TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-07-04 00:00:00.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')))
```

The issue is that is generating the query using `TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-07-04 00:00:00.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')` instead of `TO_DATE`:

```
STRT_DT >=  TO_DATE('09-JUL-14','DD-MON-YY') and 
STRT_DT <=  TO_DATE('04-JUL-18','DD-MON-YY')
```

When using `TO_DATE` instead of `TO_TIMESPAN` is way faster..
I've been debugging the code and found out where in the `DynamicLinq.cs` class is building the query:

```
 public static IQueryable Where(this IQueryable source, string predicate, params object[] values)
        {
   LambdaExpression lambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(source.ElementType,
 typeof(bool), predicate, values);
var test = source.Provider.CreateQuery(
                Expression.Call(
                    typeof(Queryable), "Where",
                    new Type[] { source.ElementType },
                    source.Expression, Expression.Quote(lambda)));
return test;
}
```

The value of lambda variable is `{Param_0 => (((STRT_DT >= Convert(7/14/2014 12:00:00 AM))) AndAlso 
(Param_0.STRT_DT <= Convert(7/18/2014 12:00:00 AM)))}`

predicate parameter value is : `"(VOYAGE_STRT_DT >= @3 and VOYAGE_STRT_DT <= @4)"`

and values is an array with the `DateTime` values : `{7/14/2014 12:00:00 AM}` and  `{7/18/2014 12:00:00 AM}` 
How can I modify that query? Any ideas? The query generated at the end is of type `IQueryable`, is it possible to modify the generated `IQueryable` query?

Comment: I don't know Linq, but the standard expressions would be `date '2014-07-14'` for a date, and `timestamp '2014-07-14 00:00:00'` for a timestamp. Or better still, it could use bind variables. What is the datatype of the `strt_dt` column?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson The datatype of the `strt_dt` column within the Oracle table is `Date`. I'm trying to find a way to modify the Linq expression. Maybe the other solution would be to create an stored procedure but that would change a lot of stuff within the project so I'm not sure that would be a good approach in this case.